# Почему не возвращается значение

Tags: javascript

У меня в файле word_rus.txt просто список слов, разделенных переносом. Не могу понять, почему первый вариант с console.log выводит в консоль массив слов, а второй вариант возвращает undefined. Понимаю, что вопрос детский, и ошибка, наверняка, детская, но я учусь...

```
 function getRusWords() {
fetch('word_rus.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        const words = text.split('\n')
        console.log(words)
    })
```

}

getRusWords();

---

```
function getRusWords() {
fetch('word_rus.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        return text.split('\n');
    })
```

}

console.log(getRusWords());

Comment: Оба варианта асинхронные, т.е. выполнение получите не в строке выхова, а точнее он будет в `.then`. В первом случае вы получили результат и вывели его. Во втором варианте результат не был выведен, а отправлен в `then`, но т.к. не был добавлен еще `then` c `console.log`, о результата не было. Т.е. вывод `console.log(getRusWords());` вывел `undefined`, т.к. сама функция `getRusWords()` ничего не возвращает, а то что было возвращено в `then` никто не получает

Comment: Спасибо. Сегодня весь день читал теорию. То что я что то делаю не так, это я понимаю. Я понимаю, как вывести данные в консоль, или в DOM. Но у меня не получается просто присвоить в переменную, которую мог бы использовать дальше.